# Security with PBKDF2 in PHP

Tags: php, security, encryption, pbkdf2

So I am storing some sensitive data in the database (a few passwords amongst other things), and I am currently using this:
https://github.com/P54l0m5h1k/PBKDF2-implementation-PHP

In short, it allows me to encrypt and decrypt data with the use of a key.

Let's say for example, that the key used is not stored on the same server as the sensitive data. If a hacker were to somehow gain access to my tables and see the encrypted data, would it be possible at all to decrypt any of it WITHOUT the key?

Answer (score 3):

`PBKDF2` is not an encryption algorithm it stands for **Password-Based Key Derivation Function 2**. So it only allows you to generate secure key based on password. So it depends on ecnryption algorithm you are using. It can be [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) or it can be [3DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3DES). And if you are using any of publicly known and approved encryption algorithms then those are secure against this kind of attacks. That is the point of encryption, attacker would need a key  or password to decipher it.